# Jumping input fields in Safari

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I'm trying to recreate [a pretty cool placeholder UI](http://dribbble.com/shots/1254439--GIF-Mobile-Form-Interaction?list=users) using only HTML and CSS, and I've almost got it ([demo](http://jsbin.com/aCUvOnI/18)). However, if you type something in an input field and tab to focus on the next, the one you just entered a value into will be offset a little bit in Safari (6.0.5) and MobileSafari (iOS 6.1). It works fine in Chrome (30).

To reproduce:

1. Focus on the 'price' input field
2. Enter a value
3. Tab to focus the next input field
4. Watch and amaze while the form eats itself

**So the question is: what's causing this and how can I fix it?**

*Note: I only really care about getting this to work in MobileSafari, anything beyond that is a bonus.*

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Title">
  <input name="price" type="text" placeholder="Price">
  <input name="location" type="text" placeholder="Specific location (optional)">
  <textarea name="desc" rows='4' placeholder="Description"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

input, textarea {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 2pt 4pt;
  padding-top: 8pt;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: lightgrey;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: top, color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .1s;
          transition-property: top, color;
          transition-duration: .1s;
}


::-webkit-input-placeholder[style*=hidden] {
  color: rgb(16,124,246);
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  top: -8pt;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible !important;
}

[name=title] {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

[name=price] {
  width: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

[name=location] {
  width: 70%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

[name=desc] {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce those results, what browser are you using?

Comment: It looks like it's working for me.  What browser are you using?

Comment: It seems even worse than you say. In Safari 5.1 I don't see the little placeholders when I've typed into the field.

Comment: IE makes it disappear too.  Works in Chrome.

Comment: Please post your code here, not just a link to jsbin.

Comment: Aww man, sorry @Barmar. Safari 5.1 probably doesn't support selecting the placeholder element. I'll edit the question to specify Safari 6.x.

Comment: @Barmar that's a lot of code to post!

Comment: Also, I suggest checking into the `tab index` attribute in HTML.. might help.

Comment: 66 lines isn't too bad.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this to your input and textarea element solves the problem:

```css
float: left;
```

Tested on Safari Version 6.0.5 (8536.30.1) and Mobile Safari

Comment: You're right, that does solve it, but only answers how to fix it and not why it happens. Would love an explanation as to why this is necessary, before accepting this as the answer.

Comment: I think it's just a webkit bug, I don't see it as an expected behaviour, maybe you should report it to the webkit project http://www.webkit.org/quality/reporting.html

Comment: Thanks @Ka., I'll go with that assessment.

Answer (score 3):

I responded to you on Twitter, but I'll also post a link here: This can be done with input + label as opposed to input + placeholder. http://codepen.io/jordanoaragao/pen/teqFw

It's been implemented here: http://womensenterprisecenter.com/

Comment: I like these, but they don't actually answer my questions. Neither does any of these examples actually do the same thing, since they act on :focus rather than the value of the input. Slight difference, but it also means in order to implement the effect I'm after necessitates the use of JavaScript, since there's no CSS selector to detect a value of an input field. Thanks for sharing though!

Comment: I think this solution should be the answer because using a `<label>` makes it an accessible solution. Placeholder text on the opposite might not be visible or read by assistive technologies such as screenreaders.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the placeholder-attribute cannot be animated. [So I made](http://codepen.io/jensgro/pen/ygsvd) a little fake-placeholder and animated this. Unfortunately, if you only use CSS, the animation will go off, if you leave the input. So I added a little bit of JS-magic to trigger the animation.