# Tabbing through input fields in mobile Safari makes browser jump

Tags: html, ios, scroll, mobile-safari

Is there a way to focus on the field, but without this jarring animation? The behavior is especially bad when the keyboard is visible.

#### Demo

http://plnkr.co/edit/9OydOFO0KUeKuaH8u70A?p=info

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input>
      <input>
      <input>
      <input>
      <input>

       ...

      <input>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: This saved me so much time and trouble. Bless you.

Comment: @BrandonBrown haha glad it helped. I can't believe this is still a bug in iOS Safari.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, this appears to be related to a focus jumping bugs in iOS. (https://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios#focus-jumping)

One neat trick that fixed it some instances was to set `float: left; clear: left;` on the input field ([Jumping input fields in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325319/jumping-input-fields-in-safari))

But that fix doesn't work if it needs to interact with a `position: fixed` element. The jumping bug persists.